# Delete blend files

Tags: modeling

How can I delete unwanted blender files?  Sometimes I run into a dead end while attempting to build something so I start a new file with a different approach but wind up with several similar but useless files e.g, xyz.blend, xyz1.blend and xyz2.blend.  The final result is xyz2 which I want to keep but my files are cluttered up with xyz and xyz1. How do I get rid of them?

Comment: What's wrong with just deleting the files using the file explorer in your system?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be a basic file management question, not about using Blender~

Answer (score 1):

You can do this from the new file dialog in Blender 2.81.

Just **right click** the file you want to delete and select *Delete* from the context menu.

Or as with everything else in blender, select the object and hit <kbd>X</kbd>

Comment: Be aware that in Blender 2.79 this would permanently delete the file, while 2.81 and later moves the files to the recycling bin / trash can.

Comment: That's an interesting point, Robert. Thanks, I wasn't aware that this had changed.